# Exclude subscriber users from user list

Tags: users, wpdb

I want to exclude Subscribers from a user list. My code is:

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT display_name FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name ASC" );
```

How can I change that so subscribers are excluded from the list?

I also looked at the get_users function in codex but it did not have an exclude by role parameter.

Edit: Or another way would be to get the results filtered by capability (one that subscribers doesn't have).

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'role__not_in' => 'subscriber'
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

How about [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#User_Role_Parameter) with the role__not_in argument.

Comment: Note: the role__not_in argument was added in WP 4.7. See Trac issue [#38135](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38135).

Answer (score 0):

This new method should work. It looks at all the capability values to find "subscriber", and hides it.

Try this query

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT display_name 
    FROM $wpdb->users WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
        SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
        WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
        AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value NOT LIKE '%subscriber%') ORDER BY display_name ASC" 
);
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a safe solution. This is for a plugin development.

Comment: Try that query instead. It should be safe to use unless Wordpress removes capabilities (which probably won't happen lol)

Comment: interesting!  I do not want it in a function. If you look at my own code, I need the results in one line for the $users variable. Can you plz update your question with this?

Comment: My mistake, when I read "User List" i thought user list from admin panel. I updated my answer, hopefully this works.

Comment: works! last question, how is this query compared to my original one when considering performance?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't say. I'm glad it worked and maybe if left open somebody else will come with a better query than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_users()` function twice to exclude the `subscribers`.

You can do something like this

```
// Gets all the subscribers
$user_query = get_users( array( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
// This gets the array of ids of the subscribers
$subscribers_id = wp_list_pluck( $user_query, 'ID' );
// Now use the exclude parameter to exclude the subscribers
$non_subscribers = get_users( array( 'exclude' => $subscribers_id ) );
```

**`$non_subscribers`** contains the non subscribers.

You can fetch the `display_name` by doing something like this

```
foreach( $non_subscribers as $non_subscriber ) {
    echo $non_subscriber->display_name;
}
```

Comment: isnt running get_users twice bad for performance? Which way is better for performance, yours or the query posted in the other answer?

Comment: `get_users` internally runs the query, so i guess if you can get something out with running the query once is better than getting it from two queries. But i am not sure if the other query is better than using `get_users` twice. Lets see if someone enlightens us regarding this :)